# Dynamically assigning user permissions for a react app with an AWS serverless backend

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

For context I built out a notes app following along with serverless stack: https://serverless-stack.com

Essentially I have a notes app, that allows users to write notes and then see all of the notes they have written as a feed on a dashboard. The database is a DynamoDb table that queries based off the userId to return a list of all notes that will populate the feed.

What I'm trying to figure out is how I would be able to dynamically assign which users can view notes. For example, the app would have users A, B, and C. User A writes a note which he then allows user C to view but not user B.

What would be the best way to accomplish this goal? I've already looked at some Role Based Access Control options, but I don't think that will work in the context of what I'm trying to do, since there would be too many hypothetical "roles" in that situation to handle all the possible access combinations, especially as the number of users grow.

The other idea I had was to keep a separate DynamoDb table that stores the relationships between the notes and the various users that would have visibility of them. So schema would be something like:

```
noteId | userId | visibility
-------|--------|-----------
  1    |   A    |   Yes
-------|--------|-----------
  1    |   B    |   No
-------|--------|-----------
  1    |   C    |   Yes
```

And the query to return available notes would have to be updated to populate the notes which have visibility set to true.

Would this be good means to manage user permissions like that? Not sure if this option would be something that scales well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would go too far to come up with a complete model that fits all your use-cases. However, I hope to be able to provide some pointers.

To model data in Amazon DynamoDB, it makes sense to consider the access patterns. They probably are the following, maybe more:

1. Get all notes owned by a specific user
2. Get all notes visible to a specific user
3. Get specific note

Given these patterns, there are a number of ways to model the data using a DynamoDB table in conjunction with a Secondary Index. Have a look at the following links for modeling guidance:

- How to model one-to-many relationships in DynamoDB: https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-one-to-many/
- Best Practices for Modeling Many-to-Many Relationships in DynamoDB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html
- The What, Why, and When of Single-Table Design with DynamoDB: https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-single-table/